# Markov's inequality for uniformly bounded functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, concentration-of-measure

**Question**: If $f$ and $g$ are two positive, increasing functions such that $f(t)\leq g(t)$ for all $t>0$ and $X$ is a positive random variable, then is it true that for all $t>0$,

$$\frac{\mathbb{E}[f(X)]}{f(t)}\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]}{g(t)}$$

under some additional assumptions (like differentiability of $f,g$ and something else) which I would like to know to make this work? It doesn't hold in general as pointed out in the comment section.

**My Work**: I just hypothesized this after working on a problem in the source below - I proved that if $f(t)=t^q$ for $q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $g(t)=e^{\lambda t}$ for $\lambda>0$, the inequality holds for comparing moment and Cramer-Chernoff tail bounds. It also trivially holds if I consider $f(t)=t$ versus $g(t)=\alpha t$ for $\alpha\geq 1$.

**Source**: In "Concentration Inequalities" by Boucheron, Lugosi, and Massart, they have a problem (2.5) on proving that moment bounds are tighter than Cramer-Chernoff bounds. I was wondering if I could weasel an argument about $g(t)=e^{\lambda t}\geq t^q$ by Taylor expansion instead of the argument in the [reference](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684633?seq=2).

Comment: THis would mean that $E(f(X))/E(g(X)) \leq \inf_{t > 0}f(t)/g(t)$, which is $0$ if $q, \lambda > 0$ and $f(t) = t^q$, and $g(t) = e^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: The exact statement in the problem I worked out is that for $t >0 $, $$\min\limits_{q\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^q]}{t^q}\leq \inf\limits_{\lambda >0} \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda (X-t)}]$$ which makes sense no?

Comment: Oh I see. This fails in general as here I'm taking the infimum over $\lambda$. Is there a way to salvage some similar inequality or no?